# Python execution works in Shell but not in Terminal

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I have a Raspberry Pi and I'm attempting to create a Python script. However the issue is that I'm unable to run the script from the Terminal, it throws syntax errors yet the same code works just fine in the Python 3.5.3 Shell.

I'm trying the simplest thing such as a `print`and I've tried various ways with the parentheses and quotation marks, yet no luck with executing the script in the terminal.

I'll include a simple Imgur link of a screenshot, showing how the code is successfully executed in the Shell but not in the terminal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEi5k.jpg

The code:

```
print ("test")
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: your raspberry pi is using `python2`. Try `print "test"`, it will work.

Comment: That returns "Error: no such file "test".

Comment: The shebang says it should be run with bash. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I removed the shebang yet no luck.

Comment: Please paste code, not images. We cannot copy-paste and modify images, but we can do that with plain text.

Comment: @janos Updated the main post, included the code..

Comment: Don't remove it, change it to `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Thank you, @JulioDanielReyes ! That solution worked. I am grateful. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Hi @Jocke, glad it worked! would you please accept answer?

Answer (score 2):

The error was that your terminal didn't know that the code you tried to execute was python, therefore it tried to execute it with the bash interpreter.

Adding the correct shebang to specify the use of the python interpreter fixed the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

print("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can execute python scripts, i.e. the script `boa.py` from terminal by `python boa.py`